# jabber messages for file transfer

Tags: python, xmpp, ejabberd

I'm interested in finding out the xml messages which are sent among two clients when a file is transferred from one to another(just for fun).

So far I've been finding out the xml messages involved in actions such as authentication, setting the status, sending a message etc. by using jabber.py - I modified xmlstream.py's network write function to print the data just before it writes it to the network.

However, jabber.py does not provide functions for file transfer. Could someone:-

1. Suggest a Python library that does that?
2. Or, show me some place where the xml messages sent from client to client would be documented.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at

- [XEP-0096: SI File Transfer](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0096.html)
- [XEP-0234: Jingle File Transfer](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0234.html)

for details (**Edit:** about the XML).

**Edit:** I don't know about the current support for these XPEs in Python libraries.